# EmberJs - How to update the Handlebars template content after the view load?

Tags: ember.js, handlebars.js

Is there any way in Ember to update the Handlebars template content and re-render the dependent views dynamically?

I tried by using `Ember.TEMPLATES` and `Ember.Handlebars.compile` method, but it didn't worked and the [JSFiddle is available here](http://jsfiddle.net/VTP4n/), so any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

I don't know why you're attempting to do this, but if it's just for testing sake, here is a working fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/VTP4n/2/.

Ember caches the template inside the view as a computed property, so I'm overriding it and calling `rerender` on the view. I wouldn't even consider using this in production though.

Up until recently, it was as easy as overriding the template and then calling `view.notifyPropertyChange('template')`, but with the new container stuff, it's a lot more complex to do it cleanly.

Comment: thanks for the reply and the reason for doing this is we have a feature in our application to edit the templates inline, so can you please share the items which needs to be taken care while doing this.

Comment: Depending on the scope of your inline editing, I'd suggest implementing a custom `template` function on your views, rather than hacking into `container`.

Answer (score 0):

Capture anything you want the user to manipulate in the template as a property of the view/controller and create a binding for it either as computed property or attach an observer to it. This way you can create a view dynamically and append it anywhere you want in your document.